# Flutter Geofencing with multiple geofences

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am a beginner in Flutter and I am trying to develop an app that will run on both Android and iOS. The app should have the ability to add several geofences and track when a user enters or leaves any of the geofences and identify which geofence triggered the event. Is there a way to do this? I have seen examples for easy_geofencing, but they do not seem to identify which geofence triggered the event. Is there a Flutter package that will do this? I am trying to avoid using iOS and Android native code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [geofence_service](https://pub.dev/packages/geofence_service)?

When you register a geofence, you provide, amongst others, its id which you later receive in the listeners.